# Why does IPC::SysV->shmget respond with EINVAL?

Tags: perl, ipc, shared-memory, sysv

I am currently running perl 5.8.8 on a server and I'm trying to install 5.14.

I configured it to usethreads and use64bitint and otherwise the defaults it suggested.

make ran without problems, but make test is failing, on

```
../cpan/IPC-SysV/t/ipcsysv.t
../cpan/IPC-SysV/t/shm.t
```

thus:

```
# ./perl harness ../cpan/IPC-SysV/t/shm.t ../cpan/IPC-SysV/t/ipcsysv.t 
../cpan/IPC-SysV/t/shm.t ...... IPC::SharedMem->new failed: Invalid argument at t/shm.t line 54.
../cpan/IPC-SysV/t/shm.t ...... Dubious, test returned 22 (wstat 5632, 0x1600)
No subtests run
../cpan/IPC-SysV/t/ipcsysv.t .. 1/38 shmget failed: Invalid argument at t/ipcsysv.t line 100.
# Looks like you planned 38 tests but ran 17.
# Looks like your test exited with 22 just after 17.
../cpan/IPC-SysV/t/ipcsysv.t .. Dubious, test returned 22 (wstat 5632, 0x1600)
Failed 21/38 subtests

Test Summary Report
-------------------
../cpan/IPC-SysV/t/shm.t    (Wstat: 5632 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 22
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
../cpan/IPC-SysV/t/ipcsysv.t (Wstat: 5632 Tests: 17 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 22
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 38 tests but ran 17.
Files=2, Tests=17,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.01 usr  0.00 sys +  0.13 cusr  0.00 csys =  0.14 CPU)
Result: FAIL
```

Both of these tests are reporting 'Invalid argument', but when I look at the source, I can't see anything that looks invalid. I'm not really sure how to proceed... any pointers?

**UPDATE**

I ran

```
 strace perl -MIPC::SysV=IPC_PRIVATE,S_IRWXU -e 'shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, 8, S_IRWXU) or die $!'
```

on two servers: one which is having these problems and one which is not.

There was a lot of output, but what appears interesting is this:

GOOD:

```
.
.
.
stat64("/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi/auto/IPC/SysV", 0x9d7f0c8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/auto/IPC/SysV", 0x9d7f0c8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/auto/IPC/SysV", 0x9d7f0c8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi/auto/IPC/SysV", 0x9d7f0c8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/auto/IPC/SysV", 0x9d7f0c8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/auto/IPC/SysV", 0x9d7f0c8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi/auto/IPC/SysV", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat64("/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi/auto/IPC/SysV/SysV.so", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=15072, ...}) = 0
stat64("/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi/auto/IPC/SysV/SysV.bs", 0x9d7f0c8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
futex(0x4d106c, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
open("/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi/auto/IPC/SysV/SysV.so", O_RDONLY) = 4
read(4, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\3\0\1\0\0\0 \v\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
fstat64(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=15072, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 17948, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 4, 0) = 0x588000
mmap2(0x58c000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 4, 0x3) = 0x58c000
close(4)                                = 0
close(3)                                = 0
shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, 8, 0700)            = 7438344
exit_group(0)
```

BAD:

```
.
.
.
stat64("/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi/auto/IPC/SysV", 0x8d290c8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/auto/IPC/SysV", 0x8d290c8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/auto/IPC/SysV", 0x8d290c8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi/auto/IPC/SysV", 0x8d290c8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/auto/IPC/SysV", 0x8d290c8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/auto/IPC/SysV", 0x8d290c8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi/auto/IPC/SysV", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat64("/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi/auto/IPC/SysV/SysV.so", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=15072, ...}) = 0
stat64("/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi/auto/IPC/SysV/SysV.bs", 0x8d290c8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
futex(0x94306c, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
open("/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi/auto/IPC/SysV/SysV.so", O_RDONLY) = 4
read(4, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\3\0\1\0\0\0 \v\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
fstat64(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=15072, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 17948, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 4, 0) = 0x6a4000
mmap2(0x6a8000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 4, 0x3) = 0x6a8000
close(4)                                = 0
close(3)                                = 0
shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, 8, 0700)            = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
open("/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2528, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb7dbe000
read(3, "# Locale name alias data base.\n#"..., 4096) = 2528
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0xb7dbe000, 4096)                = 0
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "Invalid argument at -e line 1.\n", 31Invalid argument at -e line 1.
) = 31
exit_group(22)                          = ?
```

So, it appears that the same thing is happening on both servers, it's just that on one, I see 
    shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, 8, 0700)            = 7438344

and the other, I see

```
shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, 8, 0700)            = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
```

The versions of IPC::SysV are the same on both servers... but it looks to me that this isn't relevant, and that the problem is the the code making the system call... right?

What next?

** UPDATE 2 **

After some googling, I ran the following:

GOOD:

```
#  cat /proc/sys/kernel/shmmax
4294967295
```

BAD:

```
# cat /proc/sys/kernel/shmmax
0
```

So, that explains the EINVAL, since (from [the man pages](http://linux.die.net/man/2/shmget))

> **EINVAL**
>
> A new segment was to be created and size < SHMMIN or size > SHMMAX, or no new segment
>   was to be created, a segment with given key existed, but size is greater than the size
>   of that segment.

Now, my question is, is there a good reason why this might be set at zero?

Comment: Also, you should probably report this to the IPC::SysV maintainer

Comment: It seems that IPC::SharedMem->new() fails with an invalid argument because shmget() fails.
The shmget definition is `int shmget(key_t key, size_t size, int shmflg);`, just as the new() constructor.
Something goes wrong, maybe with the shmflg parameter...
How old is your kernel? Have you tried to build on a more recent kernel?

Comment: Please reduce to the smallest case that will show this error.  IIUC, looking at the test and sources, that's something like:  `./perl -Mblib_FIXME -MIPC::SysV=IPC_PRIVATE,S_IRWXU -e 'shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, 8, S_IRWXU) or die $!'`

Comment: Thanks to all. I've reduced this to the simplest case and run an strace. See above for updates

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem solved.

The `/etc/sysctl.conf` file contained the following:

```
kernel.shmmax = 137438953472
```

This is a 64 bit value, but the system is a 32 bit system.

As a result, the `SHMMAX` value was being set to 0, making all calls to `shmget` fail.

Changing it to

```
kernel.shmmax = 4294967295
```

And using

```
echo 4294967295 >/proc/sys/kernel/shmmax
```

I changed the value of `SHMMAX` and the test completed successfully.